# How to connect java code with Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have read few of the documentation available on google to connect my piece of code of java with azure cosmos db but its too complex.

Is there is any simpler way to achieve this ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Please edit your question** and include the code you're using now to connect to Cosmos DB account. Also tell us why you think the current approach you're following is complex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below Code Should Work. 
It's a Simple Spring-Boot Application. If required you can convert it into normal maven application.

All the methods are getting called from **connectToDB()**.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.ConnectionPolicy;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.ConsistencyLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DataType;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.Database;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentCollection;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.Index;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.IndexingPolicy;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.RangeIndex;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.RequestOptions;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class HelloCosmosApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloCosmosApplication.class, args);
    }

    private DocumentClient client;

    @RequestMapping("Connect")
    public String connectToDB() throws DocumentClientException, IOException, ParseException {

        // Making the connection with COSMos DB account
        client = new DocumentClient("https://something-something.documents.azure.com:443/",
                "someKeyShouldBeYourPrimaryKeyIfYouWantToPerformReadWriteOperation==",
                new ConnectionPolicy(), ConsistencyLevel.Session);

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        // Use JSONObject for simple JSON and JSONArray for array of JSON.
        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) parser
                .parse(new FileReader("C:/STSTestWorkspace/HelloCosmos/src/main/resources/test.json"));


        //This one is added to take date and time.
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        data.put("id", date.toString());   // we are taking ID as a random value.

        this.createDatabaseIfNotExists("javaDB");
        this.createDocumentCollectionIfNotExists("javaDB", "testJava");
        this.createDocumentIfNotExists("javaDB", "testJava", data);

        return "Success";
    }

    // Create Database
    private void createDatabaseIfNotExists(String databaseName) throws DocumentClientException, IOException {
        String databaseLink = String.format("/dbs/%s", databaseName);

        // Check to verify a database with the id=FamilyDB does not exist
        try {
            client.readDatabase(databaseLink, null);
        } catch (DocumentClientException de) {
            // If the database does not exist, create a new database
            if (de.getStatusCode() == 404) {
                Database database = new Database();
                database.setId(databaseName);

                client.createDatabase(database, null);
            } else {
                throw de;
            }
        }
    }

    // Create Collection
    private void createDocumentCollectionIfNotExists(String databaseName, String collectionName)
            throws IOException, DocumentClientException {
        String databaseLink = String.format("/dbs/%s", databaseName);
        String collectionLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s", databaseName, collectionName);

        try {
            client.readCollection(collectionLink, null);
        } catch (DocumentClientException de) {
            // If the document collection does not exist, create a new
            // collection
            if (de.getStatusCode() == 404) {
                DocumentCollection collectionInfo = new DocumentCollection();
                collectionInfo.setId(collectionName);

                // Optionally, you can configure the indexing policy of a
                // collection. Here we configure collections for maximum query
                // flexibility including string range queries.
                RangeIndex index = new RangeIndex(DataType.String);
                index.setPrecision(-1);

                collectionInfo.setIndexingPolicy(new IndexingPolicy(new Index[] { index }));

                // DocumentDB collections can be reserved with throughput
                // specified in request units/second. 1 RU is a normalized
                // request equivalent to the read of a 1KB document. Here we
                // create a collection with 400 RU/s.
                RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                requestOptions.setOfferThroughput(400);

                client.createCollection(databaseLink, collectionInfo, requestOptions);

            } else {
                throw de;
            }
        }

    }

    // create Document
    private void createDocumentIfNotExists(String databaseName, String collectionName, JSONObject json)
            throws DocumentClientException, IOException {
        try {
            String documentLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s/docs/%s", databaseName, collectionName, json);
            client.readDocument(documentLink, new RequestOptions());
        } catch (DocumentClientException de) {
            if (de.getStatusCode() == 404) {
                String collectionLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s", databaseName, collectionName);
                this.client.createDocument(collectionLink, json, new RequestOptions(), true);
            } else {
                throw de;
            }
        }
    }

}
```